# how to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

tried upgrading spring-boot from 2.5 to 2.6 facing the below issue, not sure what went wrong

bellow are some of the dependencies which we mention version, others are all we don't mention the versions and takes from parent

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.31</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.89</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.67</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

```
20:27:56.606 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
```

resolution for the error

Comment: Spring Cloud is tied to specific versions of Spring Boot. When upgrading SPring BOot you must probably also upgrade Spring Cloud to a newer/compatible version. Your version isn't compatible thus you get these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like this is a known [issue](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-aws/issues/799) for this version

Comment: As @M. Deinum commented This problem would be resolved when you use the compatible version of 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I had dependencies some of which were compiled by later version of Java.